# C# Sudoku Puzzle

Tags: c#, asp.net, sudoku

Hi All I'm trying to create a sudoku puzzle using classes, arrays, and for loops. Pretty much wanting to generate the puzzle from the code behind aspx. The problem that I'm running into is how to display the contents of a for loop that creates an array of the textboxes.

I have a class called sTextBox.cs that creates a textbox and contains the other features of the puzzle. Then I have a class puzzleBox.cs that creates an array of sTextBox. This is the inside of a single square of the puzzle. Then I have the Puzzle class that creates an array of the Box(). This way it should create all the textboxes needed for a puzzle. What I simply am trying to figure out is how to get the puzzle to display on the aspx.

Code:

sTextBox.cs

```
public STextBox()
{
    txtBox = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox();

}


public System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox getTextBox()
{
    return txtBox;
}
```

Box.cs

```
private SodokuTextBox[,] sTBox;

public Box()
{
    sTBox = new SodokuTextBox[3,3];

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++ )
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++ )
        {
            sTBox[i, j] = new SodokuTextBox(); // make new sodoku textbox
        }
    }
}
```

puzzle.cs

```
{


private Box[,] boxArray;


public Puzzle()
{
    boxArray = new Box[3, 3];

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {

            boxArray[i, j] = new Box(); // make new sodoku textbox




        }
    }
```

I've been trying to insert things into a table somehow but all the methods that I found didn't seem to work for me. Thanks for any help!!

EDIT:

Ok so after working through things a little further I think what I need to do is to somehow put the individual textboxes in a table cell then have the table be the bigger (square of 9) then put the big table into another table cell within the puzzle (square of 81) Not sure if this is the best way to approach this or how to really do this if at all possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place either a PlaceHolder or a Panel on the ASPX page, give it an ID, and then you can programmatically add controls to it in the code behind like this:

```
MyPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(textBox);
```

Alternatively, you can pass in a reference to either the Panel or PlaceHolder to the Puzzle constructor:

```
public Puzzle(PlaceHolder placeHolder)
```

If you want to create a table in your code, you can do so as follows:

```
    Table tbl = new Table();
    tbl.ID = "table1";

    placeHolder.Controls.Add(tbl);

    for (int row = 0; row < 5; row++)
    {
        TableRow rw = new TableRow();


        TableCell cell = new TableCell();

        Label text = new Label();
        text.Text = "text";

        cell.Controls.Add(text);
        rw.Cells.Add(cell);

        tbl.Controls.Add(rw);

    }
```

Comment: Ok so I'm trying to do this within my function that creates the textbox. Unfortunately it is within a class and does not like to reference the aspx item (panel). I'm getting the feeling I'm trying to do the impossible haha

Comment: You will need to either pass in the panel to a method in your class from the PageLoad of your codebehind or have a method on your class that returns a ControlCollection that the PageLoad will call to get the controls.  There is no way to put something on a page without any reference to either the page or some control on the page.

Comment: Ok so after working through things a little further I think what I need to do is to somehow put the individual textboxes in a table cell then have the table be the bigger (square of 9) then put the big table into another table cell within the puzzle (square of 81) Not sure if this is the best way to approach this or how to really do this if at all possible.

Comment: You can create tables in code as well, Table, TableRow, and TableCell are all classes you can create:  Table tbl = new Table();  TableRow rw = new TableRow(); TableCell cell = new TableCell();Label text = new Label();
            text.Text = "text";

            cell.Controls.Add(text);
            rw.Cells.Add(cell);

            tbl.Controls.Add(rw);

Comment: My project is still not quite there yet, but I was able to get a little further looking at the code you posted. I have 81 boxes showing now, just not in a sudoku pattern yet. Thanks so much for your quick help!!!